# QMediaPlayer freezes when changing source a second time

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtmultimedia

The first time I call `setSource()` everything goes smoothly. However if I try to call `setSource()` after media has started playing, even when calling `stop()` beforehand, the program freezes.

The specific lines of code are:

```
self.player.stop()
self.player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile((self.playlist[self.track].fileName())))
```

Annoyingly it runs perfectly in debug mode, so not really sure what the error is.

I was expecting it to simply change the media and then become ready to play the next song.

Comment: It's probably best to wait until the media-state has changed to `StoppedState` before setting a new source. Use the `stateChanged` signal to do that.

Comment: just tried setting it to wait until it reaches StoppedState and it still freezes

Answer (score 0):

I solved the freezing by: setting player.position to player.duration, and then waiting until it reaches EndOfMedia before loading the next source